# ADMU7704E: Failed while trying to start the Windows Service associated with server

Tags: websphere, contrast

I am trying to use the "Contrast for eclipse" plugin.
I followed the instruction in this [link](https://support.contrastsecurity.com/entries/22525566-installing-on-websphere) to install Contrast on Websphere : I have added this line to the Generic JVM arguments :

```
-javaagent:D:\my_project\.metadata\.plugins\com.contrastsecurity.eclipse\contrast-engine-3.1.4.jar -Xshareclasses:none
```

But after this operation and when starting the Websphere server manually from the command line, I'm getting this error  : 
 
`ADMU7704E: Failed while trying to start the Windows Service associated with server: dmgr;
probable error executing WASService.exe: Starting Service: FRWLMCRFF9CellManager01
Service failed to start.  startServer return code = -1`

The content of the log file : `native_stderr.log` is not that clear for me :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/my_project/.metadata/.plugins/com.contrastsecurity.eclipse/contrast-engine-3.1.4.jar!/com/aspectsecurity/contrast/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/my_project/.metadata/.plugins/com.contrastsecurity.eclipse/contrast-engine-3.1.4.jar!/com/aspectsecurity/contrast/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [com.aspectsecurity.contrast.org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00020002
...
...
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
MM_MarkingScheme::scanClass:0x013EA5D5 [0x013EA140 +0x00000495]
0x00550E08
---------------------------------------
JVMDUMP006I Traitement de l'événement de dump en cours "gpf", détails "" - Veuillez patienter.
JVMDUMP007I JVM demande un dump System en utilisant 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\core.20150513.150320.6048.0004.dmp'
JVMDUMP010I Dump System écrit dans C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\core.20150513.150320.6048.0004.dmp
JVMDUMP007I JVM demande un dump Snap en utilisant 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\Snap.20150513.150320.6048.0005.trc'
JVMDUMP010I Dump Snap écrit dans C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\Snap.20150513.150320.6048.0005.trc
JVMDUMP007I JVM demande un dump Java en utilisant 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\javacore.20150513.150320.6048.0006.txt'
JVMDUMP010I Dump Java écrit dans C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\javacore.20150513.150319.6048.0003.txt
JVMDUMP013I Evénement de dump traité "gpf", détails "".
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This error means the JVM crashed.  If your javaagent has native code, you should try to verify that your native code has not overwritten memory owned by the JVM.  Otherwise, if your javaagent is pure Java, then this is a JVM error, and you will need to open a PMR with IBM to get assistance.

Comment: I can't figure out whether my javaagent has native or pure code, could you please explain how can I proceed ?

Comment: If it's not your javaagent, then you either need to work with the vendor that (or community) that created it, or skip that step and open the PMR with IBM.  There's not much the stackoverflow community can do to assist with a JVM crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the vendor. Our agent is pure Java.

My first suggestion would be to try the newest version of the plugin, which we released today. It delivers our 3.1.6 version of the Java agent.

WebSphere uses the IBM JRE, which we've found to have less mature support for the Instrumentation API than HotSpot, and generally more crashy. This is especially true for the older versions. That being said, we've got a lot of customers working just fine on the platform.

I would report the issue to IBM, copy our support email, and try to get a PMR.

Maybe we can try to work around their bug -- what version of WebSphere and JRE are you using?

Comment: Websphere version : 7.0.0.0 and JRE version : 1.6.0

Comment: That is a successful platform for other customers. Try opening a PMR with IBM.